# Typo3 Typoscript how to add class= url alias in menu

Tags: typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

Based on newest Typo3 6.2.4 with bootstrap_package Onepage.
I try to add a class parameter to my a-Tag in the menu. I need to have:

```
<a href="index.php?id=3#products" class="VALUE_FROM_PAGE_ALIAS">TITLE</a>
```

The "VALUE_FROM_PAGE_ALIAS" should be replaced by the value given to the Typo3 Page Alias value.
Find below the Typoscript (coming from bootstrap_package OnePage)

```
lib.navigation.main >
lib.navigation.main = COA
lib.navigation.main {
10 = HMENU
10 {

    special = directory
    # Hier die Page ID der Eltern Seite ( System Folder ) angeben
    special.value = {$plugin.bootstrap_package.settings.uidsOfMenu}

    excludeDoktypes = 6,7,199,254,255
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-main">|</ul>
        expAll = 1
        noBlur = 1
        NO = 1
        NO {
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            stdWrap.cObject = CASE
            stdWrap.cObject {
                key.field = doktype
                default = COA
                default {
                    20 = TEXT
                    20 {
                        typolink {
                            parameter.data = TSFE:id
                            section {
                                field = alias
                                ifEmpty = p{field:uid}
                                ifEmpty.insertData = 1
                            }
                            ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
                            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                            #wrap = |<span class="bar"></span>
                        }
                        field =  nav_title // title
                    }
                }
                3 = TEXT
                3 {
                    field = nav_title // title
                    typolink {
                        parameter.field = url
                        ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
                        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                        #wrap = |<span class="bar"></span>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            #allWrap = <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">|<span class="bar"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
            allWrap = <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">|<b class="caret"></b></a>
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown">|</li>
        }
    }
    2 < .1
    2 {
        wrap =  <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>
        SPC = 1
        SPC {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="divider"></li><li class="dropdown-header">|</li>
        }
        IFSUB >
    }
}
```

}

Should i use a "LOAD_REGISTER" for this or what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
typolink.additionalParams.class.field = alias
typolink.additionalParams.class.htmlspecialchars = 1
```

Comment: i cannot get a dynamic value. if i use:  `3 = TEXT
                    3 {
                        field = nav_title // title
                        typolink {
                           parameter.field = url
                           title.field = abstract // description // title
                           ATagParams = class = myharcodedClass
                        }
                    }`  

i get: class="myharcodedClass" but i cannot achieve to get another dynamic value there. Why?